# MariaDB + Galera, Galera does not replicate mysql.user

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a mariadb galera with 2 nodes, when I create an user in db1, this does not replicates en db2 but if I create a db in db1, it repplicates in db2!!!! 
Any idea for mysql.user replicate?

Answer (score 2):

The Galera replicate only DDL (Data definition language) and **innodb**-DML (Data manipulation language).

If you create a user by "insert into mysql.user ...." it is **myissam**-DML --> NOT REPLICATED

If you create a user by "create user ...." it is DDL --> replicated.

Answer (score 2):

By default on `MariaDB` the database `mysql` and then `mysql.user` are `MyISAM`, 
for change all tables on `InnoDB` prove this:

```
 mysqldump -uroot -p --no-data  -R --triggers mydb > mydb_schema.sql
```

Then dump out the data:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --no-create-info  -R --triggers mydb > mydb_data.sql
```

Change Storage Engine

```
sed -i.bak 's#MyISAM#innodb#g' mydb_schema.sql
```

and after import mydb_schema

```
mysql -u root -p < mydb_schema.sql
```

and finally the data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are creating the user with create user / grant all privileges statement?
Galera is designed to work perfectly on InnoDB, but the tables in the mysql database (like the user table) are in MyISAM what can cause stupid errors.